# Gain scheduling H infinity control

Tags: matlab, control-theory

I'm working on gain scheduling H infinity control design using `hinfgs`, built in function in Robust Control Toolbox.

When I provide polytopic model to the `hinfgs` function, I get the following error:

> Error using `hinfgs` (line 46)
>   Not available when the E matrix varies.

Even it won't work for very simple parameter dependent system such as a mass spring system.
MATLAB code is given below:

```
c = 5;
k = 300;
m = [2 8];
Ws=tf([10],[1 10]);
Wk=tf([5],[1 5]);
for i = 1:length(m)
    GP_pollist=[];
    A = [0 1; -k/m(i), -c/m(i)];
    B = [0; -1/m(i)];
    C = [1 0];
    sys(i)= ss(A,B,C,0);
    [ap,bp,cp,dp]=linmod('G_P_mass_spring');
    GP_all_lti{i}=ltisys(ap,bp,cp,dp);
    GP_all{i}=[ap bp;cp dp];
    GP_all_ss{i}=ss(ap,bp,cp,dp);
    GP_pollist=[GP_pollist,GP_all_lti{i}];
end
GP_pol=psys(GP_pollist);
r=[1 1];
[gopt,K_all_hinf,R,S] = hinfgs(GP_pol,r,0,1e-2,1e-2);
```

It will be highly appreciated if someone could help me out here.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Please provide a concise statement of what you would like.

Comment: I'm trying to design gain scheduling controller.

Comment: you are missing the generalized plant description. The plant has no `Bw` but only `Bu`

Comment: could you please help me how can add Bw ? As i extracted the filters and plant from simulink model using 'linmod'

Comment: I don't have your G_P_mass_spring so I don't know how I can help. Can you add the linearized model to the question and explain what the goal is ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your *E matrix* (which typically is just the identity) in, e.g.,

```
Ex' = A(p)x + Bu
```

indeed varies with the parameter `p` you have set it to zero explictly in the list of the system matrices provided to `hinfgs` (for all systems except from the first system).

```matlab
% first system
g_one = ltisys(a0,b0,c0,d0); 
% ...
% p-th system
g_p = = ltisys(ap,bp,cp,dp,0*ap); % with that, we set E=0*A=0 here
% ...
GP_pollist = [g_one, g_p]
```